# Pronunciation of "о"

Tags: произношение, word

Can someone explain the correct pronunciation of "o"? (I know it may vary but maybe there's some rule of thumb that I can take advantage of).

Take **just** the word *мост* for example, it seems that "*o*" is pronounced as *o*, but when you combine it with *на* as in:

> *на мосту*

The pronunciation starts to sound like "a", is this because of the dative case?

Also, can we generalize this? Like, can I say that whenever you get the dative case of a noun the first "*o*" is pronounced as *a*?

Comment: without stress it's [a], with stress it's [o]

Comment: @VadimLanda the wikipedia article is rather succint, I'd like a more thorough answer

Comment: The rule of thumb is it becomes "a" when it's unstressed (but I don't think it helps _a lot_, since it's not that easy to say if that O is stressed or not in a particular case).